# What is the meaning of “cop” in: “if London cops it, he'll cop it”?

Tags: meaning, british-english, slang

What is the meaning of the text in bold:

> He says **if London cops it, he'll cop it.** And not to worry, Dad.

I have found these meanings for *cop* in The Free Dictionary, but none of them seem relevant to the sentence.

> **1.**  **[cop](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Cop) <sup>2</sup>**
>   <sub><sup>tr.v. copped, cop·ping, cops</sup></sub>
>   a. To get hold of; gain or win
>   b. To perceive by one of the senses
>
> **2.** To take unlawfully or without permission; steal.

[image]

Comment: Think of 'cop' as meaning 'get'.  "If London gets it, he'll get it".  'It' presumably being a nuclear blast.

Comment: Unfortunately for one trying to understand this in isolation, "cop" has multiple, relatively unrelated, meanings.  But David's comment sounds to be a good guess.

Comment: Given that the book/movie is about a nuclear attack on Britain, and the previous lines refer to building a bomb shelter, it's reasonable to assume that "London" refers to the city.  I doubt that the writer would have named a character "London" simply because it would be too confusing and distracting.

Comment: To _cop it_ means quite simply to be killed. If London (the city) gets blown to bits in a nuclear blast, then so will he.

Comment: This question should be reopened, the OP did do her research and as clearly shown, the meaning of the verb "cop" in "somebody will cop it", appears to be not covered by the definition. It is not at all obvious the meaning of the phrase cited by the OP, especially since it  is BrEng slang.

Comment: It deserved to stay opened, and besides I used to be a Londoner myself, so I couldn't bear to see a BrEng slang question being imprisoned :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In British English 'cop it' can mean a few things but one of two of those things is certainly being referred to. From http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cop:

> **1.2 (cop it)** British **Get into trouble:**
>   *will you cop it from your dad if you get back late?*
>   **1.3 (cop it)** British **Be killed:**
>   *he almost copped it in a horrific accident*

London is the city. The story is about nuclear war and Ron is referring to London being hit by a thermonuclear bomb. Both definitions would apply to that but I think the 'be killed' definition is the most likely. London would be annihilated and that could be thought of as being killed. Ron could hardly 'get' the blast without being killed. Calling being hit by a nuclear explosion as 'getting into trouble' would be to ridiculously understate it (he is British though, so that is a possibility).

That the immediate conclusion to the statement is that Ron is not going to build a shelter confirms this: Ron has said he will die if London dies.

Comment: Jinx! Beat me to it by nine seconds (though I got there first with the comment).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Hehe yes. If I had know you were too I would have typed faster. Both answers are much of a muchness. I'm happy to delete. Do you want to copy anything from mine before I do?

Comment: No reason to delete either—the fact that two answers say the same thing is only a problem if one comes a long time after the other. When they’re simultaneous, we usually just leave both. :-)

Comment: @Soudabeh I did by a resounding nine seconds! :) Please tick whichever you feel answers it best (or indeed wait for a better answer).

Comment: @Mari-LouA I already have.

Comment: Reopened, and  hopefully your answer and Janus' will gain more recognition.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you for your efforts. Not for my sake of course (recognition shmecognition is my motto) but for the sake of truth and justice and all that.

Answer (score 3):

The verb *to cop* has quite a few meanings, the most basic of which is ‘seize, grab’. The sense relevant here is definition 1.1 (of the verb) as given in the [Oxford Dictionaries Online article](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cop):

> Incur (something unwelcome)

If you *cop* something, it is forced on to you, you get it without wanting it. You can cop the blame for something; you can cop a bad deal from someone (meaning that you’re treated unfairly by them); you can cop one (‘one’ referring here to a punch) on the side of the head, etc.

Idiomatically, when you cop *it* (definitions 1.2 and 1.3), the ‘it’ in question can either be trouble in general, or more specifically **death**, which seems to be the sense intended here. So when you *cop it*, you incur death—in other words, you’re killed.

It’s a very colloquial, perhaps even slangy, expression, but it’s common enough in British English. In the script excerpt he, Ron is saying he accepts that *if London gets killed* (= blown to smithereens) *in a nuclear blast, then he will get killed too*.

Comment: *Penny for the blind, mister.*  
Hey, fancy voting to reopen this question? Only one vote missing.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Done! Didn’t realise it had been closed.

Comment: Alleluia. Thank you sir, very grateful I am. Much obliged! (*sound of bowing and scraping of shoes*)